# Getting an App Store ID without publishing an iOS app

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm currently developing a React Native app, which will be published on the iOS App Store eventually.

I'm currently attempting to build deep links within the app, but I require an App Store ID before I can do this.

Having searched on Google - there's no current answers to this query, but it feels quite important, and I can't find any documentation on it.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get an App Store ID without publishing the app?

Comment: Yes, you can create an apple developer account and active it (you need to pay 100$) and do anything you want to do with your app. When you feel you're ready to publish, just upload your app to appstore connect and hit publish. (It's more complicated than that)

Comment: A developer account is different to an App Store ID though. I don’t want to publish the app yet (and won’t for a while), but I do need an App Store ID which is correct for the app.

Comment: Are you talking about the bundle id? You can just use anything that is unique. Apple recommends using your domain name reversed, so something like "com.mydomain.mygreatapp"

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I currently have the same issue?

Comment: Sorry never got an answer. I ended up not using deep links.